# Window in Window with PySimpleGUI list

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to get a gui in a gui ish.

The layout I have for the first gui:

```py
    layout = [[sg.InputText(size=(31,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Button('(', size=(5,1)), sg.Button(')', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('C', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('<<', size=(5,1))],
              [sg.Button('7', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('8', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('9', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('/', size=(5,1))],
              [sg.Button('4', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('5', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('6', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('*', size=(5,1))],
              [sg.Button('1', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('2', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('3', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('-', size=(5,1))],
              [sg.Button('0', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('.', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('=', size=(5,1)), sg.Button('+', size=(5,1))]]
```

Then there is a second layout:

```py
    layout = [[sg.Text('Text:', size=(9,1)), sg.Input()],
              [sg.Text('Amount:', size=(9,1)), sg.Slider(range=(1,1000),default_value=1,size=(35,15),orientation='horizontal', resolution=10)],
              [sg.Text('Speed(m/s):', size=(9,1)), sg.Slider(range=(1000,1),default_value=1000,size=(35,15),orientation='horizontal', resolution=100)],
              [sg.Text('Delay:', size=(9,1)), sg.Slider(range=(1,10),default_value=1,size=(35,15),orientation='horizontal')],
              [sg.Button('Start')]]
```

The root layout is:

```py
layout = [[sg.Listbox(values=['Wifi Passwords', 'Email Bot', 'Auto Clicker', 'Calculator', 'Spambot', 'Upload File', 'IP Lookup', 'URL Resolver', 'Youtube Downloader', 'Is Leap Year', 'Space Shot','URL Shortener','Tic Tac Toe', 'Random Password', 'Fizz Buzz', 'Pong', 'Turtle Race'], size=(30, 15), key=0, enable_events=True)]]
```

How would i set this up so that when i pick 1 option from the list in root the layout that matches it shows up in a sub window below it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for you,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 16))

def main_window(function_list):
    layout = [[sg.Listbox(values=function_list, size=(30, 15), key='Func_List',
        enable_events=True, select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE)]]
    return sg.Window("Main Window", layout, finalize=True)

def calculator():
    size = (5, 1)
    layout = [
        [sg.InputText(size=(31,1), key='-OUTPUT-')]]+[
        [sg.Button(char, size=size) for char in line] for line in
            [['(', ')', 'C', '<<'], ['789/'], ['456*'], ['123-'], ['0.=+']]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Calculator", layout, finalize=True, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values =window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()

def slider():
    text_size = (9, 1)
    options = {'size':(35, 15), 'orientation':'horizontal'}
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Text:',       size=text_size),
         sg.Input()],
        [sg.Text('Amount:',    size=text_size),
         sg.Slider(range=(1,1000),default_value=1,   **options, resolution=10)],
        [sg.Text('Speed(m/s):', size=text_size),
         sg.Slider(range=(1000,1),default_value=1000,**options, resolution=100)],
        [sg.Text('Delay:',      size=text_size),
         sg.Slider(range=(1,10),  default_value=1,   **options)],
        [sg.Button('Start')]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Slider", layout, finalize=True, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values =window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()

func_dict = {
    'Wifi Passwords': None,
    'Email Bot': None,
    'Auto Clicker': None,
    'Slider': slider,
    'Calculator': calculator,
    'Spambot': None,
    'Upload File': None,
    'IP Lookup': None,
    'URL Resolver': None,
    'Youtube Downloader': None,
    'Is Leap Year': None,
    'Space Shot': None,
    'URL Shortener': None,
    'Tic Tac Toe': None,
    'Random Password': None,
    'Fizz Buzz': None,
    'Pong': None,
    'Turtle Race': None,
}
func_list = sorted(func_dict.keys())
window = main_window(func_list)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Func_List':
        if not values[event]:
            continue
        item = values[event][0]
        if item in func_dict:
            function = func_dict[item]
            if function:
                window.hide()
                function()
                window.un_hide()

window.close()
```